# Magento 2.4.3-P2: Illegal state - Amasty Product Parts Finder-1.11.19

Tags: search, amasty

After updating, I'm having this problem when I go to Search by Vehicle.

1 exception(s): Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Illegal state

```
#1 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->addFieldToFilter() called at [vendor\amasty\finder\Model\Finder\SearchCriteriaBuilder.php:53]
#2 Amasty\Finder\Model\Finder\SearchCriteriaBuilder->addCollectionFilter() called at [vendor\amasty\finder\Model\ResourceModel\Finder.php:220]
#3 Amasty\Finder\Model\ResourceModel\Finder->addConditionToProductCollection() called at [vendor\amasty\finder\Model\Repository\FinderRepository.php:126]
#4 Amasty\Finder\Model\Repository\FinderRepository->addConditionToProductCollection() called at [vendor\amasty\finder\Model\Finder.php:199]
#5 Amasty\Finder\Model\Finder->applyFilter() called at [vendor\amasty\finder\Observer\Frontend\ApplyFilters.php:90]
#6 Amasty\Finder\Observer\Frontend\ApplyFilters->execute() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault.php:88]
#7 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault.php:74]
#8 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php:66]
#9 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy.php:95]
#10 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php:491]
#11 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php:121]
#12 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_getProductCollection() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php:200]
#13 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1113]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1118]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:678]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor.php:617]
#17 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:578]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:555]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:525]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Category\View.php:100]
#27 Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View->getProductListHtml() called at [vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\category\products.phtml:15]
#28 include() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php:71]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor.php:23]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:273]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:303]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1114]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1118]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:678]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:578]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:555]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#85 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#86 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:606]
#87 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#88 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#89 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#90 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#91 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:149]
#92 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:510]
#93 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:140]
#94 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:975]
#95 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#96 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#97 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#98 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:347]
#99 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:260]
#100 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#101 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#102 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#103 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#104 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:95]
#105 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:120]
#106 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:23]
#107 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:264]
#108 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\index.php:29]
```

What is the reason for the search, or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: faced with a similar problem, after some debugging thinking about quitting magento.. where errors happens I added some logs, works like should be, but giving error...